# How to execute a stored procedure with parameters?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters, dynamic-sql

I have a database with 40 tables. I want to select data from a certain table by using a single stored procedure. First table `(TblSPAU1)` has 6 columns, named: `ID, COL_SPAU1_EA, COL_SPAU1_EQ, COL_SPAU1_ore, COL_SPAU1_nivel, DateTime`. Fourth table `(TblSPAU4)`, for example, has this 6 columns: `ID, COL_SPAU4_EA, COL_SPAU4_EQ, COL_SPAU4_ore, COL_SPAU4_nivel, DateTime`.  So what I want is to select data from table X from `DateStart` to `DateStop`. What I've done so far is:

```
USE [DBRapBreaza]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PS_SpauOPompa]    Script Date: 12/19/2018 15:48:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_SpauOPompa]

@DataStart datetime,
@DataStop datetime,
@val int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @sql NVARCHAR(max)
declare @col1 varchar
set @col1='ID'
declare @col2 varchar(25) 
set @col2='COL_SPAU'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @val)+'_EA' 
declare @col3 varchar 
set @col3='DateTime'

set @sql='select [ID]'+@col2+' FROM [DBRapBreaza].[dbo].[TblSPAU'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @val)+ '] WHERE DateTime between'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DataStart,121)+ 'and'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DataStop,121)+';'

END

EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql, N'@DataStart datetime,@DataStop datetime,@val int',  @DataStart, @DataStop, @val
```

I want to select, let's say, the ID and fist column from a certain table. @val represents the number of the table I want to select data from.
On `sp_sqlexec` I have a tool-tip which says that I have too many arguments specified. When I execute the EXEC, it throws me this error: `Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1. Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".`
My question is how should I execute this stored procedure?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: sp_sqlexec is no longer supported, so you should look at using sp_executesql instead. Have a read of this http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#sp_executesql

Comment: I got rid of that tool-tip message, but I still get Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1. Must declare the scalar variable "@sql" error.  Should I declare @sql in another part of the code?

Comment: Move the END to the end of the batch

Comment: I moved the last END after EXEC, but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need some spaces in your string build. Specifically, change it to:

```
set @sql= 'select [ID], '+@col2+' FROM [DBRapBreaza].[dbo].[TblSPAU'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @val)+ '] WHERE DateTime between '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DataStart,121)+ ''' and '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DataStop,121)+''';'
```

This will make your SQL look like this:

```
select [ID], COL_SPAU1_EA FROM [DBRapBreaza].[dbo].[TblSPAU1] WHERE DateTime between '2018-12-20 14:18:02.170' and '2018-12-20 14:18:02.170';
```

As opposed to the following:

```
select [ID]COL_SPAU1_EA FROM [DBRapBreaza].[dbo].[TblSPAU1] WHERE DateTime between2018-12-20 14:19:13.167and2018-12-20 14:19:13.167;
```

Which is missing:

- A comma after the first column
- Space between comma names (semantics)
- Space after the word *between*
- Quotes around the dates that will be evaluated from your parameters
- Space before and after *and* in the `where` clause on your `between` statement

This is why it's always wise to use `PRINT @sql` while testing your dynamic SQL.

Then, once you move the `END` to the very bottom of the script, change your execution to:

```
EXEC sp_executesql  
    @sql, 
    N'@DataStart datetime, @DataStop datetime, @val int',  
    @DataStart, @DataStop, @val
```

This will leave you with the following code:

```
USE [DBRapBreaza]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PS_SpauOPompa]    Script Date: 12/19/2018 15:48:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_SpauOPompa]

@DataStart datetime,
@DataStop datetime,
@val int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @sql NVARCHAR(max)
declare @col1 varchar   --missing a length here
declare @col2 varchar(25)
declare @col3 varchar   --missing a length here

set @col1='ID'
set @col2='COL_SPAU'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @val)+'_EA' 
set @col3='DateTime'

set @sql= 'select [ID], '+@col2+' FROM [DBRapBreaza].[dbo].[TblSPAU'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @val)+ '] WHERE DateTime between '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DataStart,121)+ ''' and '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DataStop,121)+''';'

--print @sql;


EXEC sp_executesql  
    @sql, 
    N'@DataStart datetime, @DataStop datetime, @val int',  
    @DataStart, @DataStop, @val;

END
```

Of note, you didn't specify a length for `@col1` or `@col3` which would default to `8` so be careful there. You never used this variable, so I'm not sure what it's purpose is.

Comment: why not add in the  `;`s?

Comment: I admit @Hogan the leniency with them that's allowed makes me lazy.

Comment: I know the feeling -- I point it out because errors like the OP are describing is sometimes the result of missing them.

Comment: any improvements or anything i missed that you can see?

Comment: yes there are some variables that are declared but not used.

Comment: I commented on that in the bottom. Not sure why they were there either (or not given a length)

Comment: oh yeah... I was looking at the code not the comments.  Sorry.

Comment: I started the stored procedure with the idea of selecting 3 columns from the table. After I've seen the errors I started to display just @col2. Now my question is how should I execute the stored procedure in order to get some values from the table?
I tried like this: execute [PS_SpauOPompa] '2018-12-12 10:10:10.997', '2018-12-14 14:50:20.680', 4 (I put it before the last END)
But the error now is: "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).". Why do I get this error?

Comment: We’d have to see your new code in its entirety. It’d be best to open a new question.